# Multiple rows with same id but different row names

Tags: php, mysql, rows

I have two tables with different number of columns and column name.

tab a:

```
ID   nome       cognome    messaggio  testo      orario     ip
---  ---------  ---------  ---------  ---------  ---------  ---------
1    a          a          a          a          a          127  
2    b          b          b          b          b          111
3    a          a          tt         qqq        h          127
```

tab b:

```
id   nome       cognome    email
---  ---------  ---------  ---------
1    t          t          t
```

I would like to use %t% within both the tables and proper publisher all columns of both tables as I do?

print:

```
ID   nome       cognome    messaggio  testo      orario     ip         email
---  ---------  ---------  ---------  ---------  ---------  ---------  ---------
1    t          t          null       null       null       null       t
3    a          a          tt         qqq        h          127        null
```

Comment: you can use UNION ALL i guess

Comment: Can you add some details? If you can edit the question adding expected result (coherent with table sample), this can help to receive a better answer.

Comment: maybe you should consider using a specialized text table/index like '%a%' are very badfor perf

Comment: i edit the result with the print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in search of something like this:

```
    SELECT ID as id, nome, cognome, messaggio, testo, orario, ip, NULL AS email 
      FROM `tabA` 
     WHERE nome LIKE '%t%' OR cognome LIKE '%t%'  OR messaggio LIKE '%t%'  OR testo LIKE '%t%'

 UNION ALL

    SELECT id as id, nome, cognome, NULL as messaggio, NULL AS testo, NULL as orario, NULL AS ip, email 
      FROM `tabB` 
     WHERE nome LIKE '%t%' OR cognome LIKE '%t%'  OR email LIKE '%t%'
```

<kbd>**[sqlFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/235468/4)**</kbd>

`UNION` is used to combine the result from multiple `SELECT` statements into a single result set. `UNION` remove duplicate rows, `UNION ALL` returns all rows. The column number of each `SELECT` statement must be equal, so I specified all fields in each `SELECT`, setting `Null` for non-existing columns.

**Please note** that above use of `LIKE` seriously affects performance.

---

- Read more about [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html)

Comment: As you can read in my answer, the two select statements must return same column number. The returned field names are those of **first** select. you can choose only fields that you want, but if first select return (i.e.) 5 columns, second select must return 5 columns.

Comment: You are starting now with this project or your database structure is preexisting?

Comment: i start now :) but ok tnks man u are precious and sorry for my bad english

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://holowczak.com/database-normalization/) and [this](http://www.mrwebmaster.it/sql/normalizzazione-database_7420.html)

Comment: ma sei italiano? aahahaha ok bastava dirlo prima grazie mille :D comunque pensavo ci fosse un metodo più sbrigativo rispettoall' uion per fare il tutto visto che ho delle tabelle con tante colonne mi viene difficoltoso e lungo controllare le differenze delle colonne ...va bè lavoro noioso ma che si deve fare grazie ancora